# How do I make faint words in search bar that go away when you click/type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

So, for instance facebook's search bar has faint word that says "search", but when you click on the bar, it becomes blank and you may begin typing, when you click away the "search" goes back.

Similarly, SO's ask a question title box has faint words that go away when you start typing.

I'm not too sure what this effect is called, but I'm wondering if theres a jQuery plugin that helps to achieve this. This isn't particularly difficult to program, but I thought why reinvent the wheel if someone already made a plugin for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/inputLabel) that does just that!

#### Update

I've since moved it to GitHub and rewrote it to address some issues. Enjoy! Feel free to email me where you use it, so I can feel useful :)

Comment: Off topic: not many of these watermark style plugins play well with validation or other scripting. I think `.val()` should really be overridden to return "" if the text is the default one. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Box9 I agree. I wrote this a while ago now, and probably should update the plugin to be more in alignment with my current thoughts on usabilty, etc.

Comment: @Box9 I have rewritten the plugin and moved it to GitHub. Your thoughts would be much appreciated - feel free to email me. Cheers.

Comment: @alex, I've taken a quick look and I like this approach much better. I might take a closer look another day (maybe even fork it) but just immediately: I don't think you need the `objs.each` loop, and you may run into problems when the input has no `id` ;)

Comment: @Box9 I think I require the `objs.each()` because the selector may return multiple elements (plus I like the encapsulation). Also, the plugin silently fails it can't find a label (you can also pass one in when invoking the plugin). [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/w4tVG/).

Comment: @Box9 Actually, I don't know why I used that second loop now - I'm sure it'll come to me when I can think straight again (it's 2am here) :P

Comment: @alex, ah you're right about the id. It won't break anything, I was just worried about the naked: `$('label[for = "' + id + '"]')`

Comment: @Box9 I have rewrote a great deal of it *again* :). If it can't find a `label`, it will look for the `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 has a feature called "placeholder" that achieves this. For example:

```
<input name="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

Of course, HTML5 isn't supported by all browsers, so javascript would do the trick elsewhere.

Comment: Dude you rock, that's exactly what I'm looking for! I think it will work since HTML 5 is now supported by the top dog browesers. Thanks so much!